# Is every finite $d$-dimensional matrix group generated by $d$ elements?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, discrete-geometry, linear-groups

The question is in the title. If $\Gamma\subset\mathrm{GL}(\Bbb R^d)$ is a *finite* matrix group, can it be generated by (at most) $d$ elements?

I suspect that this hope is too naive, but I have no counterexamples. I would also be interested in bounds on the number of generators.

Comment: For complex linear groups, this is false. The central product $Q_{8} \ast C_{4}$ ( where the centre of the $Q_{8}$ is contained in the $C_{4}$) needs $3$ generators, but is isomorphic a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. Offhand, I don't know a real counterexample, but I suspect there is one. The best general bound for finite complex $d$-dimensional linear groups is roughly $3d/2$  (see a paper by L.G. Kovacs and myself circa 1991).

Comment: The reference for the paper I mentioned is  Proc AMS,112,2,(1991),357-364.

Comment: Later comment: As Derek Holt's answer shows,  my suspicion about the existence of a real counterexample was not correct.

Comment: Regarding complex reflection groups, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group#Well-generated_complex_reflection_groups.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes.

In Theorem 1.2 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869313002160). the authors (Colva Roney-Dougal and myself) prove that  if $G \le {\rm GL}(n,F)$ with $F$ a field, where

(a) $G$ is finite;

(b) either $G$ is completely reducible or ${\rm char} F = p$ and $O_p(G)=1$; and

(c) $F$ does not contain a primitive fourth root of unity,

then $d(G) \le n$.

This is best possible when ${\rm char} F \ne 2$,  because there is an obvious embedding of $C_2^n$ in ${\rm GL}(n,F)$.

Comment: Note that this implies the same conclusion for finite $G\le \mathrm{GL}(\lfloor n/2\rfloor,K)$ for $K$ arbitrary field of char zero.

Comment: @YCor True, but the bound of $3d/2$ mentioned in Geoff Robinson's comment is more accurate. This also holds in characteristic $p$ provided that $O_p(G)=1$.